# Get total from table input as grand total in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table that makes automatically 2 calculations:

1. Calculation of numbers of days after the selection of date started and date end from two input date field with calendar, result is stored is field (days)
2. Multiplication of 3 fields (horse* days* price), result is stored ind field (total).
   There is a button that when we click on it a new row is added.

How can i calculate the **grand total of numbers of days** and the **grand total of the total to display the results in a row below the table**?
And i want to grasp the input values in post so that i store them in table using php.

1- table

```
 <table class='table'>
<tr>
  <th class='th'>Nbr/horses</th>
  <th class='th'>dateStart</th>
  <th class='th'>dateEnd</th>
  <th class='th'>Nbr/days</th>
  <th class='th'>Price</th>
  <th class='th'>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='td'><input type='number' min='1' name='horse' class='horse'/></td>
  <td class='td'><input type='date' name='dateStart' class='datepicker dateStart'/></td>
  <td class='td'><input type='date' name='dateEnd' class='datepicker dateEnd'/></td>
  <td class='td days'><input type='text' name='days'/>0</td>
  <td class='td'><input type='number' min='1' name='price' class='price'/></td>
  <td class='td total'> <input type='text' name='total1'/></td>
  <td class='td'><button type='button' class='button'>+</button></td>
</tr>
```

2- functions

```
 let update = function(lineNode){
let dateStart = $(lineNode).find('.dateStart').datepicker('getDate');
let dateEnd = $(lineNode).find('.dateEnd').datepicker('getDate');
let days = Math.floor( (dateEnd - dateStart) / (3600*24*1000) );
days = days >= 0 ? days : 0;

$( lineNode ).find('.days').text( days );

let horse = parseInt( $(lineNode).find('.horse').val() );
let price = parseInt( $(lineNode).find('.price').val() );
let total = horse * days * price;

$( lineNode ).find('.total').text( total+' €' );
 }

  // add line after click
  let addRow = function(lineNode){
   let clone = lineNode.cloneNode(true);
   $(clone).insertAfter(lineNode);
   reloadEffects();
   }

  let reloadEffects = function(){
  $('.hasDatepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').attr('id', '');

$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('.horse, .price, .datepicker').change( e => {
  update(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
});
$('.button').click( e => {
  addRow(e.target.parentNode.parentNode);
});
```

};

```
// Start

 reloadEffects();
```

Answer (score 0):

for the total

```
var sum = 0;
$(".total").each(function(index,value){
sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).find('input[name="total1"]').val());
});
//Sum in sum variable 
console.log(sum);
```

Apply the same for days !

Working Fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8nLaact/4/)

Comment: how hard i try to make your exemple work, i fail. May be if you put it a fiddle it will help me more...

Comment: sure , i will add a link once i make it

Comment: added , please check it

Comment: thank you for your reply, but We always have one row displayed, only click can display others rows. And grand total must be displayed automatically in field no need to click on a submit button to get the total...Thanks for you time.

Comment: can't you implement the same function but on that button click and add the row dynamically ?

Comment: i understand but your function can't work on that function  let update = function(lineNode){....